# How to set an OID for a specifical row column Postgres database table using Go

Tags: postgresql, go

I am a little confused as how I can set the OID of a particular row and column pair.

I want to create a large object to store a pdf file in the data base.

I am going to use the pgx driver for the Golang sql package to do this operation, which to my understanding uses the pgx.create function to create an oid value. The specific function prototype is shown below and the link to the documentation is: https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/large_objects.go

[image: PGX function prototypes]

I have initialized my table to have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    category VARCHAR(100),
    picture OID,
    picture_w INT,
    picture_h INT,
    data_sheet OID,
    price NUMERIC(10, 2)
);
```

I have the following in the pg admin view to show you what I see with a partially initialized row:

[image: Partially internalized table row]

In the row, I would need to set the oid value in the picture and data_sheet column. At which point I can use the pgx.open command to upload the pdf file.

How would I be able to specially be able to target those specific fields such that I can use the pgx.open command?

Perhaps I am confused about the core mechanism that sets the oid value, but so far I am not able to set it for a specific cell and retrieved it to use it with the golang pgx driver.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I did try to use the select lo_create() command on the server side to force set the oid value in postgres but when loading up the row, it didn't show any indication of an update had occurred.

---- FIX -----

Hello All,

IT seems like I was doing two mistakes:

1. I needed to run the open command and store the oid that was provided which would be store in my postgres table manually for future retrieval of the large object.
2. After the Exec function I needed to use the commit function to make the change happen.

I hope this helps anyone else facing this problem.

Comment: Don't use large objects.

Comment: Use large objects, but [make sure you need to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-intro.html): *storage system called **“TOAST”**... makes the large object facility partially obsolete. One remaining advantage of the large object facility is that it allows values up to 4 TB in size, whereas TOASTed fields can be at most 1 GB. Also, reading and updating portions of a large object can be done efficiently, while most operations on a TOASTed field will read or write the whole value as a unit.*

Comment: Are you really really sure about large objects? A pdf is much easier to handle as a file than as a collection of records. It also has an impact on your backups and restore of a backup. Vacuum must also be done "manually", autovacuum doesn't handle orphaned large objects: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/vacuumlo.html

Comment: Hello All, 

Though googling it seemed like Large Objects seems like the best way to go about storing pdf information in postgres, but I will look into Toast and implement that to improve the function of the code. 

I am confused as to why people don't prefer large objects? Is there some underlying performance issue that I am not aware of?